# How to change drop down list value in ASP.NET (VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I was wondering how to change 2nd drop down list value after I selected the 1st drop down list value.

The best example is country and state.  After user selected country, the state value should change accordingly.

I am still new in ASP.NET and I know in PHP it can be easily done using javascript.

May I know how to do it in ASP.NET using VB language?

Answer (score 3):

You need to handle the [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event of country drop-down.
The dropdown should have the `autopostback` set to true.

Capture the selected index (probably the country id) and populate the states based on countryid

Answer (score 0):

This is called cascading drop downs in asp.net

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-ajax/use-aspnet-ajax-cascading-drop-down-control-to-access-a-database

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like what have been done at [Simple Way to Implement Country/State/City Dropdown List in ASP.NET (VB)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38231/Simple-Way-to-Implement-Country-State-City-Dropdow)